# set timeout for a token in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, timeout, devise, token

How do i set a timeout for a given authentication token? After the timeout, the token will be deleted and the user won't be able to use it on his requests.

I'm using rails 3 and devise.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this feature too, but didn't find a way to do it directly.

You can reset the authentication token on each sign-in and use the rememberable in-between:

in your application controller, in after_sign_in_path_for():

```
resource.reset_authentication_token
```

in devise.rb:

```
config.remember_for = 1.day
```

Or you can create a cron-job to periodically clear the invalid authentication_token entries from the users table.

Comment: thanks ! i'm using the token as an api_token. what will happen if the users logs in from different devices/browsers ? a new token will always be generated and the only one device will be able to communicate  with the api (using the token). i want a token to be generated once and be available until a "logout" is called or a timeout is passed. do you know any "best practice" about api token handling ?

Comment: I understand you, I think that the authentication token is like a replacements for user/password, and usually user/password don't have expire time (usually).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you are looking for, but this is a simple option in Devise.
If you set the following option in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

`config.timeout_in = 30.minutes`

then Devise will expire the token after 30 minutes of inactivity. The same operations that Devise does for session authentication should also work with the `authentication_token`.

I have used that in my current project and tested it using `Timecop` gem:

```
it "should timeout without activity after 30 minutes" do
    auth_token = @user.authentication_token

    get "/frontend/users/#{@user.id}.json?auth_token=#{auth_token}"
    response.status.should == 200

    Timecop.travel(45.minutes.from_now)
    get "/frontend/users/#{@user.id}.json?auth_token=#{auth_token}"
    response.status.should == 401 

    Timecop.return
end
```

Also, I don't believe that the token follows the same analogy as user/password combination as mentioned in one of the comments, since you wouldn't store your password in plain text but you do with your token. I would recommend resetting the token after each logout as well.

Answer (score 1):

At devise initializer file

```
#/config/initializers/devise.rb

# ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
# The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
# time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
config.timeout_in = 1.day

# If true, expires auth token on session timeout.
config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = true
```